# Vim: unexpected behavior of c-n in insert mode

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> in insert mode to insert the next matching word, my cursor jumps to the next blank line instead. This happens only to a `.markdown` file as far as I can tell.

I didn't map `c-n` to anything in my vimrc (which I could post here if that would help), nor do I have a `markdown.vim` in `ftplugins`. Meanwhile, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> works as expected. How can I go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is a buffer-local mapping set up by a system-wide ftplugin.  You can check for buffer-local mappings, and show which script set them, by running this command while in the buffer in question:

```
:verbose imap <buffer>
```

You can also check what scripts have loaded, including filetype plugins, with this command:

```
:scriptnames
```

Comment: Thank you. It's the sparkup plugin, which is supposed to affect only html files (residing in `ftplugins/html` even). That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Some ftplugins explicitly load other ftplugins.